# Set theory - functions: Given that $|A|=|B|$, how to prove that $|A^C|=|B^C|$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Given that $|A|=|B|$ (the cardinality of set $A$ is equal to the cardinality of $B$).

How can I prove that $|A^C|=|B^C|$ (the cardinality of the set of all functions from $C \longrightarrow A$ is equal to the cardinality of  the set of all function from $C \longrightarrow B$).

I understand that I have to find a bijection $h: A^C \longrightarrow B^C$, means that $g$ receives a function $f: C\longrightarrow A$, and return a function $g: C\longrightarrow B$.

I am not sure how to approach finding such a bijection and therefore asking here for help. Much appreciated!

Comment: We know there is a bijection $\varphi:A\to B$. So now, given a function $f:C\to A$, how can we obtain a function $C\to B$? Think of it, there is really just one (natural) way.

Comment: Maybe a function $g: C \longrightarrow B$, such that it's entire image is all $f(a)'s$ for every $a$ that is in the image of $f$? Tell me if i'm in the right direction.

Comment: @natitati that's overly complicated.

Comment: I'm afraid that I need another hint then :(

Comment: @natitati No need to overcomplicate. We have two functions: $f:C\to A$ and $\varphi:A\to B$. From these two functions, what is a way to get a function from $C$ to $B$? You didn't use $\varphi$ at all in your comment.

Comment: Oh... I see, compose the 2 functions, that way we get a function from $C$ to $B$. And then all is left is to prove that it's a bijection.

Comment: @natitati Indeed, the required map takes $f$ to $\varphi\circ f$.

Comment: Thanks. And how do I properly say that it's a bijection? Let's start with one-to-one, can I just say that for every $h_1, h_2 \in A^C$, if $h1 \neq h2$, then $\varphi \circ h_1 \neq \varphi \circ h_2$? And what about on-to?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:
Let  $\psi$:$A\longrightarrow B$ be a bijection since A and B are equinumerous.Then; define a function such that; $\phi$:$A^C\longrightarrow B^C$ as $\phi(f)=\psi$$\circ$$f$ then observe that
$\psi$$\circ$$f$:$C\longrightarrow$$B$.Since all functions in $A^C$ is different they generate
all different functions(hence it's an injection)from C to B(so the output is definitely in $B^C$
). Also, all the functions in $B^C$ are covered since $\psi$ is an surjection $\forall$x$\in$$B$ $\exists$$b\in A$ such that $\psi(b)=x$
Thus, the $\phi$ generates all functions from B to C.